# Call a Generic method by reflection in java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

How to call a Custom Generic method by reflection in java?

```
class Person
{
  public <T> void print(T t)
   {
      System.out.println(t.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Generics are erased at compile time, they only provide extra information to the compiler to determine errors.  They do not actually change the signature of the method in the `.class` file.

This means that you call a generic method by reflection in Java exactly the same way as you would call a non-generic method in Java, except that instead of specifying a type of `T`, you would specify a type of `Object`.

There are so many tutorials on how to call a regular method by reflection that I hesitate to add yet another; however, if you really need direction on how to call a method by reflection, please add a comment below and I'll add the necessary code.

If you find that things are not working as expected, you can always run `javap` on the compiled class file to verify that you are using the right objects in the argument list.  It might be possible that if you specify a `<T extends List>` type generic signature, the resulting parameter object might actually be a `List` object.

Comment: indeed, sorry. I will delete the comment

Answer (score 16):

This works for me.

```
Method method = Person.class.getMethod("print", Object.class);

method.invoke(new Person(), "this is a string");
method.invoke(new Person(), 273);
method.invoke(new Person(), new Object());
```

printing

```
this is a string
273
java.lang.Object@addbf1
```

Of course the theory behind this is explained beautifully in [@Edwin's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739387/343955)

Answer (score 7):

To highlight the point given in Edwin's answer, where we are using extends in a generic type: if you have a class like

```
GenericHibernateDao<T extends Serializable>
```

, and a method

```
public T save( T entity ) {};
```

to invoke the method save using reflection you have to use the Serializable class, i.e., you  need to use:

```
Method method = GenericHibernateDao.class.getMethod(methodName, Serializable.class);
```

and not the Object.class as the parameter, since we are using

```
<T extends Serializable>
```